# how to add cloned git project to another parent git project as a submodule?

Tags: git, github

Question is not very complicated.

To develop my own project `myproject`, I git clone several 3-rd party projects `libxxx`, `libyyy` and `libzzz`.

```
    myproject/
    ├── .git/
    ├── libxxx/
    │   ├── .git/
    │   └── ....
    ├── libyyy/
    │   ├── .git/
    │   └── ....
    ├── libyyy/
    │   ├── .git/
    │   └── ....
    ├── ...
```

I used `git clone` command download these three library repositories. I also `commit` some of my code after cloned these three projects. However, I just noticed that these three subdirectories are not tracked by `myproject` repo. And one of these three projects has updated to new version. So in this case, is it possible to use `git` commands to **auto-resolve** these three libraries as submodules and keep the version as same as the one when I cloned them.

I think the most straightforward way to ask is: How to automatically and recursively add cloned git repo to a parent repo as submodules?

---

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cloned repos from the main repo and then add them back as submodules.

`rm -rf libxxx`

Then:

`git submodule add https://github.com/user/libxxx`

Repeat for all libraries.

Add and commit your changes.

---

Now in the future if the developers update your submodules, you can the following command to update them to their tip:

`git submodule update --recursive --remote`